# Why do I get an "Access Denied" message intermittently? How can I change this? Should I?

Tags: windows-xp, firewall, port

Windows XP SP3

I use utorrent. Occasionally, in the logger I will get this message: "Error opening Windows firewall: 0x80070005 Access is denied". It is not always there, it is intermittent.

1. Can I change this without opening myself to viruses, loggers, etc.?
2. Should I change the firewall to allow this access?
3. How would I change this?
   I am using Microsoft Security Essentials, all up to date. Also utorrent is up to date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Microsoft Answers: [Error opening Windows firewall: 0x80070005 Access is denied](http://social.answers.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vistasecurity/thread/200f5140-c2dd-48a5-8cdb-0d8c82ade3cf)

> It is a two steps process,
>   1. Make sure the torrent port is open in the Windows Firewall
>   2. Open the BT client using "RUN AS ADMINISTRATOR"

Also check with this test (if this works, I expect you can ignore other warnings):
'`http://www.utorrent.com/testport?port=[Incoming-Conn-Port]`'.

Where, '`Incoming-Conn-Port`' is the port number at,

- `uTorrent Menu`

  - `Tools`

    - `Preferences`

      - `Connection`

        - `Port used for incoming connections`.

There is also some discussion at the uTorrent forum:
[Error opening windows firewall 0x80070005 access denied](http://forum.utorrent.com/viewtopic.php?id=51158).

Comment: Lots of information, thanks. +1.
"Port used for incoming connections" does not work. I will try to follow the first advice.
Regards,